# UIView, animate, completionblock, UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uialertview

I have an app with a login screen that hosts a sign in button and a sign up button, using reachibility if I detect that I can't reach the internet I hide those buttons by showing a covering view

```
 self.coveringview
```

Now I do some simple animation playing with the alpha of this view, once that is done, I want an alertview to popup to tell the user what happen, in this code you can see I am doing that by having the alert.show in the completion block of the animatewithduration.

the bahvior is not what I want, the alert pops up too fast without showing the user the fade out I want it to show, what can I do?

```
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(netStatus == NotReachable) {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                  message:@"Unable to connect to the server.  
     Please check your internet connection and try again."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                                self.coveringView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // this is the problem here, I need to make this alert show up after  
                             the fade out occurs completely
                             [alert show];
                             self.coveringView.hidden = NO;
                         }];
}
else {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                   animations:^{
                      self.coveringView.alpha = 0.0;
                   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      self.coveringView.hidden = YES;
                   }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your `self.coveringView.hidden = YES` from your Interface Builder and set just `alpha = 0`

```
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(netStatus == NotReachable) {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                  message:@"Unable to connect to the server.  
     Please check your internet connection and try again."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                            self.coveringView.alpha = 1.0;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // this is the problem here, I need to make this alert show up after  the fade out occurs completely
                      if(finished){
                         [alert show];
                      }
                     }];                     



}
else {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                   animations:^{
                      self.coveringView.alpha = 0.0;
                   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                      if(finished){
                      self.coveringView.hidden = YES;
                      }
                   }];
```

Comment: Still not doing it, it pops up too fast, I think there's an issue with multi threading here maybe??

Comment: Still not doing it, I think there needs to be another delay.

Comment: try to initialize the allertview inside the completion block

Comment: can you do the last try for me, I edit the answer in few mins

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39783/discussion-between-mirko-catalano-and-eddie)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both setHidden and an alpha of 0.0  They both will make the view so that it doesn't intercept touches.  Your hidden/notHidden is likely conflicting with the alpha changes.

Try simplifying like this:

```
NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(netStatus == NotReachable) {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                  message:@"Unable to connect to the server.  
     Please check your internet connection and try again."
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                                self.coveringView.alpha = 1.0;
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //I need to make this alert show up after the fade out occurs completely
                             [alert show];
                         }];
}
else {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                   animations:^{
                      self.coveringView.alpha = 0.0;
                   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   }];
}
```

Comment: hi, well this is a simplification of another topic but doesn't resolve the original problem, still the alert is showing up abruptly.